# Is there anything wrong with my proof of Cantor's intersection theorem?

Tags: general-topology

> Let a compact topological space $(X, \mathcal{T})$ contain a shrinking sequence of closed, nonempty sets $\{F_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$. Prove that $\cap_{n=1}^\infty F_n$ is nonempty.

For each $F_n$, let $\{U_k\}_n$ be the most refined open covering of the sequence of refinements) over $F_n$. Because $F_n$ is shrinking, we have the chain
$\{U_k\}_1 > \{U_k\}_2 > ... $. Now each open covering of a closed set must contain the closed set and also the neighborhoods around each of the limit points (in order to be open), making them strictly greater than the open set in question. Therefore $\{V_k\} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \{U_k\}_n$ is non-empty and is an open cover of $X = \cap_{n=1}^\infty F_n$. Because $X$ is closed (infinite intersection of closed sets) and therefore compact, $X$ has a finite subcover, which would be impossible if $X = \{\}$

Comment: Sorry, I cannot make sense of your first sentence.

Comment: Every set has an open covering and some open coverings are more refined than others. I am selecting the greatest lower bound on this sequence of refinements of $F_n$.

Comment: The lim inf of the open coverings may mot be open.  For example: unit interval $[0,1]$.any open set containing an end point will have a smaller open set containing this end point and the lim inf will end at that end point and will not be open.  You will need a better proof.

Comment: @TomislavOstojich (i) why are you doing that? and (ii) why is there such a thing?

Comment: Lord Shark the Unknown, I need to construct a decreasing sequence of open covers in order for this prove to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like you are trying to do something like this:

Suppose $F_n\neq \emptyset$ but $\bigcap_nF_n=\emptyset$.

Then, $\mathscr A=\{F_n^c\}_n$ is an open cover of $X$:

let $x\in X$. If $x\notin F_n$ for any integer $n$, then $x\in F^c_1.$ If $x\in F_n$ for some integer $n$, let $j$ be the greatest integer such that $x\in F_j$. Thus is possible since $\bigcap_nF_n=\emptyset$. Then, $x\in F^c_{j+1}$.

But $\mathscr A$ has no finite subcover.

Comment: I liked your proof. It was very lucid.

Comment: Glad to help. I left my proof as it was, because I think it's smoother that way. But if you re-post the edit you made to my answer, as your own answer, I will be happy to upvote it.

Comment: Mathematleta I posted my answer...but I'm going to still ensure that you keep the coveted green checkmark to you because you're a sweetheart. :)

Answer (score 1):

Why use all those excessively complex limit things?
Assume $\cap_n F_n$ empty.
Thus X = $\cup_n(X - F_n)$
Take a finite subcover C.
Thus exists n with $F_n$ = $\cap${ X - K : K in C }.
So oh my, $F_n$ is empty.

Exercise.
Give a real quick example why compact is necessary.

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: I don't understand the leap between "Take a finite subcover C [of what?]" and "thus exists n with F_n..."

Comment: Each X - K is one of the F's.  As there are finite many of them and they are decreasing, their intersection is the smallest F in that finite collection. @TomislavOstojich

Comment: Oh okay. After reading your comment and the original ten times it now makes perfect sense.

Comment: For the exercise: if it isn't compact, then a finite subcover will not necessarily exist, meaning that ∩{ X - K : K in C} might be the empty set?

Comment: Yes, give an example. @TomislavOstojich

Comment: The sequence $\{\overline{F_n}\}$? @WilliamElliot

Comment: Huh?  @TomislavOstojich.  Consider the reals and the closed sets [n,oo), n in N.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\{\overline{F_n}\}_{n=0}^\infty$ be the open cover, and let $C$ be a finite subcover of it. Look carefully at the requirement for C: $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}\,\exists p \in X$ such that $p \in F_n$ but $p \not\in F_{n+1}$. Therefore $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}(\overline{F_n} \in C)$, contradicting finiteness. Therefore there exists an open cover without a finite subcover, a contradiction.